# In visual Studio how do I change cursor from replacing my text

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, text-editor

my Visual basic seems to replace characters in front of it and only occurs between brackets.

Can someone please tell me how to change it back to normal?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the <kbd>Ins</kbd> key to switch between *insert mode* (where text moves to the right as you type) and *overtype move* (where text to the right is overwritten by the new text you type). The cursor changes to show which mode you are in. This behaviour is common in Windows programs.

Comment: I dropped my keyboard then everything was being overtyped lol. Thank goodness for SO!